# What does a class overflow do

Tags: html, css

I have no HTML or CSS experience but trying to figure out what exactly this line of code means

`<div class="overflow-100">`

It has an affect on how wording appears on our portal and not sure if it's limiting words to 100 characters, 100 pixels or something else

Comment: Do you have tried this? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Comment: Class names are purely user data. Neither HTML nor CSS assign any special meaning to them. I suggest you inspect the source code with the browser tools and determine what styles are applied to the element and where they are defined.

Comment: Where did you see this?

Answer (score 1):

`overflow-100` is a user defined class that css selectors can target. Without seeing selector/s targeting `overflow-100` we have no idea what declarations it applies. Open the document in the browser, open [dev tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools) (`f12`), inspect element (`ctrl+shift+c`) and hover over the div with the class `overflow-100`. In the [styles tab](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/edit-styles) find a rule with a selector `overflow-100` and you will see css declarations it applies. Googling for those rules will give you a understanding of the effects of the `overflow-100` class.

Answer (score 0):

Class names are purely user data. Neither HTML nor CSS assign any special meaning to them so they don't accomplish anything by default.

Their purpose is to assign custom information that can be leveraged later from other tools (JavaScript, CSS, accesibility tools, web crawlers...).

Here's a quick and dirty showcase:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("div").forEach(function(box){
  box.classList.forEach(function(className){
    let fragments = className.split(/^foo-(\d+)$/);
    if (fragments.length === 3) {
      box.innerHTML += ` <strong>Type ${fragments[1]}</strong>`;
    }
  })
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
.foo-100 {
  width: 100px;
}
.foo-200 {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo-100 something-else">Hello, World!</div>
<div class="foo-200">Hello, World!</div>
```

To help figure out what your application is currently doing with them you can use the browser developer tools. For instance, here:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("div.bar").forEach(function(box){
  addEventListener("click", function(){
    alert("You've clicked on bar");
  })
});
```

```css
div.bar {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">Hello, World!</div>
<div class="bar">Click me!</div>
```

... you learn you have an event listener and an inline style (please note anyway that this example is an Stack Overflow snippet, which is more complex that regular code):

[image: Firefox developer tools]